# "command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1" building PIL 1.1.7

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to build python-imaging and I get this error:

```
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -IlibImaging -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.5 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/JpegDecode.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/libImaging/JpegDecode.o
    libImaging/JpegDecode.c: In function ‘fill_input_buffer’:
    libImaging/JpegDecode.c:55:12: error: ‘FALSE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    libImaging/JpegDecode.c:55:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only  once for each function it appears in
    libImaging/JpegDecode.c: In function ‘ImagingJpegDecode’:
    libImaging/JpegDecode.c:163:45: error: ‘FALSE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    libImaging/JpegDecode.c: In function ‘fill_input_buffer’:
    libImaging/JpegDecode.c:56:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: I figured it out. In the file were several booleans I needed to replace every instance of "FALSE" and "TRUE" with "false" and "true"